# How integrate cross-site multiple angular applications?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, architecture

I have one big information system consisting of diferrent subsystems. One of my objectives is to organize navigation and localization between these subsystems.

When I was generating view in backend via JSP I simply used `jsp:include` referring to special web-app which returns header with cross-site navigation and also this web-app was responsible to store user locale for all subsystems.

Now I switched to angular and found out that it's impossible to replace `jsp:include` with `ng-include`. I have 2 different ng-apps - header (coming from outside web-app) and current, say, subsystem1 ng-app. **ng-include directive in header doesn't work** because I have to bootstrap it, but I can't bootstrap header ng-app because it is absent - I'm fetching it with ng-include. Vicious circle.

Now I see one way to solve my problem:

Fetch header markup in second ng-app (non-header, subsystem1's ng-app) via ajax call to special *header-web-app*. Then, insert incoming HTML to header via simple DOM manipulations and bootstrap it manually. Disadvantage is obvious - I will make DOM manipulations in subsystem ng-app but insert HTML outside it because 2 different ng-apps must not instersect or be nested. Is it OK?

Looks like I'm inventing bicycle, so I'm asking here, **how integrate cross-site ng-apps**? **Is it possible to share data between different ng-apps in one web page?** I know, that it's possible to share data between controllers via services and factories and this is good practice. **Is there any angular-way to share data between ng-apps?**

Please, do not provide JSP-like solutions as I want to keep angular way of development and thus make only static pages with angular markup and make all server side job via ajax calls. Probably, I misunderstood angular way but now I'm seeing it exactly as I describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method #1 from [this site](http://shrestha-manoj.blogspot.com/2014/06/can-angularjs-have-multiple-ng-app.html) looks good for me. In short, any ng-app consists of markup anf js. JS can be simply loaded by `script src=...` and many ng-apps can be used as a modules of one big *root app*. Markup can be loaded by `ng-include`.